# Resistor circuit to correct impedance matching and attenuate signal by 10 decibels

Tags: amplifier, audio, impedance-matching, attenuation

I've got a Line Out on my amplifier with 100-600 ohm impedance (avg. 350). I have it connected to an effects pedal that has a 1M ohm input.

Right now the signal is clipping from the amplifier and I would like to attenuate that with a resistor only configuration, and simultaneously adjust the impedance each side sees. I'm looking for just 10dB of attenuation, or 1/3rd the volts.

Fix:

- Amp needs to see 10K ohms on the other side instead of 1M ohms.
- Pedal usually expects 1K ohms on the other side instead of 100-600 ohms (avg 350).
- 1/3 volts at the pedal inputs is desired attenuation.
- All using unbalanced connections.

With this configuration below, the amp now sees 10.3k ohms and the pedal now sees 1k ohms. And the volts is 3.33V instead of 10.

Any problems that you see? I tried T and Pi configurations and they didn't work. By adding the resistor at the bottom it all seems to compute. Not sure if I did this right.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you replace the battery with a 2 pin AC gen and add Probe for Vpp to measure each stage loss

Comment: I inserted an AC,10V and measure 19.34V peaktopeak after the input and 6.536V peaktopeak at the output. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes , you can also specify Vp instead of rms for input for ease of computing. Oh I see you used TP so same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 50 K resistor (Reference Designators - ?) is in the GND connection between the source and the load.  This is almost never a good idea in audio circuits.  Also, because your path lengths are trivially short compared to the wavelengths involved, true impedance matching is not at all necessary.  Better to go with a more simple L-pad, a two-resistor attenuator.

Why does the amp "need" to see a 10 K load a max value?  Most amp outputs care only about the load impedance being too low, not too high.  The line output from the amp probably is a resistor in series with the main output.  Combined with the input impedance of whatever is connected to it, it creates an attenuator, but that is only an issue if the thing plugged in has a relatively low impedance, such as headphones.  The main reason for the build-out resistance is to prevent a brief dead short across the amp output when something is plugged into the connector.  Of course, this is all guesswork because we don't have any information about the amp.

I recommend a 10K series resistor and 4.7K shunt resistor between the amp and the pedal.  This presents a load impedance that is greater than 10 times the amp's output impedance, and a source impedance that is less than 10 times the pedal's input impedance.

Comment: That's a lot more simpler! I just thought it had to be exactly matched to make sure it sounded best. But I'm rather new to all this!

Comment: For video and other high frequency signals, impedance match is critical to eliminating reflections in the signal cable.  For audio, the phone company has to worry about this because their runs are miles long and the signal wavelength is an issue.  For audio - no.  A better rule of thumb is that a load should at least 10x more than the output impedance, and a source should be at least 10x less than the input impedance.  Note that there are exceptions - the load impedance changes the frequency response of a guitar pickup or dynamic microphone.

Comment: How about a Balanced T configuration? If I can bury the resistors in the cable connector end, could I use the cable plugged in either way? Does it make any difference to use a T pad vs an L pad?